# Change a variable in Javascript conditioned to a end user selection

Tags: javascript, html, button

community

Through Javascript I have implemented two buttons (**Yes** and **No**).

The code implemented for that is the following:

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function bnt1() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (sessionStorage.bnt1) {
      sessionStorage.bnt1 = "Yes";
    } 
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button: " + sessionStorage.bnt1 + "." ;
  } 
}


function bnt2() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (sessionStorage.bnt2) {
      sessionStorage.bnt2 = "No";
    } 
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button: " + sessionStorage.bnt2 + ".";
  } 
}

</script>
<div style="background-color: #FFFAFA; width:50vw; text-align: center;padding: 8px;color:black">
<h2><input size="90" value="Is He (She) young?"/></h2>
<button class="btn info" onclick="bnt1()" type="button">Yes</button>
<button class="btn danger" onclick="bnt2()" type="button">No</button>
<div id="answer"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Obviously the idea is that an user can answer the questions by pressing **Yes** or **No** and then store that answer in a variable called "Answer", i.e,

**Expected output**

Suppose that the answer is **No**, then I want to see a  change

`<div id="answer"></div>` by `<div id="no"></div>`

How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you want to change the id of the div?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>   
      <div style="background-color: #FFFAFA; width:50vw; text-align: center;padding: 8px;color:black">
        <h2><input size="90" value="Is He (She) young?"/></h2>
        <button class="btn info" onclick="bnt1()" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="btn danger" onclick="bnt2()" type="button">No</button>
        <div id="answer"></div>
      </div>  

     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


        function bnt1() {
          if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {            

            sessionStorage.bnt1 = "Yes";             
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button: " + sessionStorage.bnt1 + "." ;
          } 
        }


        function bnt2() {
          if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {     

              sessionStorage.bnt2 = "No";            
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button: " + sessionStorage.bnt2 + ".";
          } 
        }

      </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna try something like this

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function bnt1() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('bnt1') === null) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('bnt1','Yes');
    } 
    var newId = document.getElementsByClassName("ans")[0].id;
    if(document.getElementById(newId)){
    document.getElementById(newId).id =sessionStorage.getItem('bnt1');
    document.getElementById(sessionStorage.getItem('bnt1')).innerHTML = "You have clicked the button: " + sessionStorage.getItem('bnt1') + "." ;
    }

  } 
}


function bnt2() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('bnt2') === null) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('bnt2','No');
    } 

    var newId = document.getElementsByClassName("ans")[0].id;
    if(document.getElementById(newId)){

    document.getElementById(newId).id =sessionStorage.getItem('bnt2');
    document.getElementById(sessionStorage.getItem('bnt2')).innerHTML = "You have clicked the button: " + sessionStorage.getItem('bnt2') + "." ;
    }
  } 
}

</script>
<div style="background-color: #FFFAFA; width:50vw; text-align: center;padding: 8px;color:black">
<h2><input size="90" value="Is He (She) young?"/></h2>
<button class="btn info" onclick="bnt1()" type="button">Yes</button>
<button class="btn danger" onclick="bnt2()" type="button">No</button>
<div class="ans" id="answer"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JS setAttribue Method to change the ID to what you want.

1) Add additional class apart from id to your answer tag.

```
<div id="answer" class="answerElement"/>
```

2) If you click on "Yes" -->
 `document.getElementByClassName("answerElement").setAttribute("id", "yes");`

3) If you click on "No" --> `document.getElementByClassName("answerElement").setAttribute("id", "no");`

Comment: HTML doesn't have any methods. `setAttribute` is a JavaScript method. :)